# How to move flutter bin file

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was working with flutter and for some reason the bat file was removed. Now flutter as been moved into another directory. How do I move it back, as my android studio project wont run and delete the unused files. Tried to earlier but it wont delete the bin file.

Pic 1 - Old flutter path

Pic 2 -  Where bat file used to be

Pic 3 - New bat file location

Pic 4 - Flutter doc error

[image: Old flutter path]

[image: Where bat file used to be]

[image: NEw flutter path]

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can relocate the flutter SDK path in Android studio.
**For Windows**
Go to `File-> Settings -> Under languages & framework section choose flutter`
**For MAC**
Click on `Android Studio-> Preferences -> Under languages & framework section choose flutter`

You will now see an option for `flutter SDK path`. From here you can relocate your SDK path.

Try restarting Android studio if that doesn't solve your problem immediately.

Comment: @ Ashutosh Stupid question, but where is it in studio?

Comment: @D.Dobins sorry, my bad. I am a Mac user. For windows, it should be under File>Settings.